# Azure Notification Hub sends pushes to registrations with expired time to live

Tags: azure-notificationhub

I've configured  my Azure Notification Hub to have a custom Registration Time to Live equals to 1 day.

However even if this TTL has expired for a particular registration, Azure Notification Hub still sends pushes there, and I receive them on my mobile devices.

Also expired registrations still visible at the Azure Notification Hub.

here is an example of  expired installation:

```
GET https://{{hub-namespace}}.servicebus.windows.net/{{hub-name}}/installations/OLEKSA3?api-version=2015-01
with response
{
    "installationId":"OLEKSA3",
    "pushChannel":"{{my-app-device-push-channel}}",
    "pushChannelExpired":false,
    "platform":"apns",
    "expirationTime":"2020-02-01T15:55:11.8088897Z", <<<<
    "tags":["o:67890","r:dev","u:3"]
}
```

Is it possible to avoid sending pushes to expired registrations? Does notification hub remove expired registrations?

Thank you

Comment: hi,if you don't mind ,you could mark the answer for others' reference on the forum,thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just for summary from this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/cc0921e0-8510-4262-9854-c944c19899b2/azure-notification-hub-sends-pushes-to-registrations-with-expired-time-to-live-and-to-registrations?forum=notificationhubs) created by yourself for others' references.

> Does notification hub remove expired registrations?

It is expected behavior for Notification Hub that expire registrations will be deleted 7 days after the TTL expiration.

> Is it possible to avoid sending pushes to expired registrations?

Not support yet so far.You post 2 points which could be improved by NH:

1. Expired registrations can still be availiable at the hub for up to 7 days (until the maintainance job clears them), and push notifications will be sent to them. Therefore, I suggested that the hub should avoid sending push notifications for expired registrations.
2. If for some reasons your device installation id has changed (for example, you are using iOS identifierForVendor property, which is unique but not constant) then hub will continue to send it push notification until you remove it (or you set the registration TTL and it will be removed by the maintainance job). This looks like an issue in hub when it unable to detect outdated channelIds.