# Azure notification hub registration expiration date does not update if time to live is greater than 1 day

Tags: azure, react-native, .net-core, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

background:

I am developing a react native app with a .net-core backend and I am using Azure notification hub to send push notifications. I don't want useless Id's piling up in the notification Hub so I would like to set a time to live on the notification hub, and everytime a user logs in I will update the hub with createOrUpdateInstallationAsync. When I set the time to live to one day I can see that the expiration time on the registrations are updating every time I log into the app, however if I set the time to live longer than this, the expiration dates stop updating.

Question:

Why does the expiration date not get updated for longer time to live, and What is the recommended way to achieve what I am trying to achieve? When I try to find answers to this question all I can see is guides on how to update the time to live.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one workaround to update expiration date
As suggested by @ehuna ,
"Make sure that you have installed the following `nuget packages` in your console app

> - Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Management.NotificationHubs -Version 2.3.2-preview
> - Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent -Version 1.38.0

Wrote the below method

```cs
  private async Task SetNotificationHubRegistrationTimeToLive()
    {
        // Login to Azure using az login
        // az account set -s <name or ID of subscription> to set the proper subscription
        // Get credentials: "az ad sp create-for-rbac --sdk-auth"
        // See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/get-started-with-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/quickstart

        var clientId = "your client id";
        var clientSecret = "your client secret";
        var tenantId = "your tenant id";

        var credentials =
                SdkContext
                .AzureCredentialsFactory
                .FromServicePrincipal(
                    clientId,
                    clientSecret,
                    tenantId,
                    AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

        var client = new NotificationHubsManagementClient(credentials)
        {
            SubscriptionId = "yoursubscriptionid"
        };

        var resourceGroupName = "yourgroup";
        var namespaceName = "yournamespace"; // this should NOT be the namespace full name beam-dev-notification-hub-namespace-free.servicebus.windows.net
        var notificationHubName = "yournotificationhub";

        var timeSpan = new TimeSpan(days: 90, hours: 0, minutes: 0, seconds: 0);
        var registrationTtlTimeSpanString = timeSpan.ToString();

        var notificationHub = await client.NotificationHubs.GetAsync(resourceGroupName, namespaceName, notificationHubName);

        await client
              .NotificationHubs
              .CreateOrUpdateAsync(
                resourceGroupName,
                namespaceName,
                notificationHubName,
                new NotificationHubCreateOrUpdateParameters(notificationHub.Location)
                {
                    RegistrationTtl = registrationTtlTimeSpanString
                });
    }
```

You will then see in  https://portal.azure.com/  in your notification  hub properties that Registration time to live is 90 days."

For more information please refer the below links:

- SO THREAD :  [Azure Notification Hub sends pushes to registrations with expired time to live](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60025249/azure-notification-hub-sends-pushes-to-registrations-with-expired-time-to-live)
- SO THREAD :  [How to update Expiration Time in Azure Notification Hub registration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39413953/how-to-update-expiration-time-in-azure-notification-hub-registration)
- Blog : [How to set expiration date for azure notification hub registration android](https://www.titanwolf.org/Network/q/2723c94f-bde3-46da-9d7d-ca6aadfc10c9/y)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can change the time to live no problem. My question is why does the expiration date not update when calling CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync. I have set the time to live to 90 days. But now when I update the installation, sometimes the expiration date updates and sometimes it does not. I'm wondering why it fails to update expiration date when the CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync executes without any errors.

Comment: Thanks @J.Kennedy, Could you please refer this MS DOC :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-registration-management#example-code-to-register-with-a-notification-hub-from-a-backend-using-an-installation

Comment: I have read the docs but this doesn’t answer my question. If it does and I just missed it, can you please provide more information about where my question is answered in the docs?